# Are there problems declaring variables in conditionals?

Tags: python, conditional-statements

Does it prevent problems to define a variable before it is re-defined in all possible branches of a conditional?

For instance should this code:

```
    # Condition could fail
    try:
        textureIndices = someExpression()

    # textureIndices is defined here if it does
    except:
        textureIndices = []

    return textureIndices
```

Be re-written as this:

```
    # textureIndices is defined early and then re-defined in the conditional
    textureIndices = None

    try:
        textureIndices = someExpression()


    except:
        textureIndices = 66

    return textureIndices
```

Or, because `except` opens other issues, is there a problem with the definition of `textureIndices` here:

```
if condition:
    textureIndices = someExpression()

else:
    textureIndices = 66

return textureIndices
```

to reduce problems?

The only difference is in the second version `textureIndices` is defined outside of the conditional.

I do not see why it matters because it is impossible for `textureIndices` to not be assigned a value in the conditional but I can see why from a housekeeping perspective it is nice to know the variable is assigned to something.

For instance *if* there was no `except` statement in the first example, then `textureIndices` wouldn't always be defined and `return` would cause an error.

However, are there problems if one does not forward define variables that are defined in both causes of a conditional?

Comment: In your first case, you use `except` rather than `except SomeError`. Since you shouldn't blanket except all errors together, it's possible that, in good practice, your variable would not exist unless you defined it earlier.

Comment: What is the source for "should be rewritten"?  The compiler and run-time system are fine with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason is it creates redundant code. It doesn't seem very apparent in this case, but take an example where you have multiple unique except statements catching multiple exceptions in your code. Imagine if someone wanted to refactor your code or add additional except statements.

```
textureIndices = None

try :
    textureIndices = [thing for thing in func()]fail

except InvalidTextException:
    textureIndices = []
    #lines to handle specific exception
except ValueError:
     textureIndices = []
     #lines to handle specific exception
except OSError:
     textureIndices = []
     #lines to handle specific exception

return textureIndices
```

If you had multiple variables that behaved this way, you can see how this quickly escalates. By declaring the base case first, you reduce redundancy.

```
textureIndices = []

try :
    textureIndices = [thing for thing in func()]fail

except InvalidTextException:
    #lines to handle specific exception
except ValueError:
     #lines to handle specific exception
except OSError:
     #lines to handle specific exception

return textureIndices
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable dictionary (`locals` or `globals` depending on the scope), is modified when you create a variable.

In one case, you're creating the variable, then modify it whatever the branch: 1 creation+assign, 1 assign (overwriting the old value completely).

In the case where you omit the beforehand creation, you only have 1 creation+assign, so technically it's faster *not* to declare it prior to the branch (one less dictionary lookup, one less useless assignment)

Apart from helping the Python IDE to complete the variable names in branches, I would say that the prior declaration is useless and even cumbersome in that case since both branches are covered (maybe an old compiled language programming reflex). The only case where it could have an interest would be a complex set of branches where you only set the variable in a few branches. Ain't the case here.

Comment: Ain't the case here but generally shouldn't you be specific in the errors you catch? Even if you just catch 2 specific errors and the rest crash your script, you have to define the default value twice and would that not defeat DRY (in a really minor way)?

Comment: Not sure what you're saying. Of course try/except without an exception type (or even `Exception`) is bad practice. It even catches CTRL+C. But that seemed unrelated to the question.

Comment: The answer just posted illustrates my point. Im suggesting the comment the OP is basing the question off doesn't apply to a blanket `except`

Comment: ok, now I understand (and this other answer is a nice addition)

Comment: Yeah, I think my point was there's a disconnect between "I think I heard" and the example the OP gave to test it out :)

Comment: now what I _don't_ understand is the downvote on my answer. I hope it's not tactical, because I _upvoted_ the other one...

Comment: @roganjosh I wasn't implying that at all of course! The downvote went away... ok, good. now I'll never know why :)

Comment: @roganjosh while we're at criticizing the OP code, `textureIndices = [thing for thing in func()]` is overkill for `textureIndices = list(func())` :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154561/discussion-between-jean-francois-fabre-and-roganjosh).

Comment: Critiquing is probably a better word :) I think it's a good question, just that the example doesn't quite illustrate the situation is which it's a bad idea to define things in `except` which only highlights a gap in understanding, and I age plenty of those :)

Comment: Age? Have* sorry